# programatically change previous button selected state

Tags: android, android-layout, android-button

I am using this code to create buttons and added this buttons in layout. When I click one of this button selected changed successfully. But what should I do here for clicking in button the previous button's selected state will be unselected.

In one word only one button has to be selected.

```
private void createButtons(String categoryTitle){
        final Button myButton = new Button(mActivity);
        myButton.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.btn_default_holo_dark_trans1);
        myButton.setText(categoryTitle);
        if (mFirstButtonSeleted){ //this is for first run only first button will be selected
            myButton.setSelected(true);
            mFirstButtonSeleted = false;
        }

        mButtonsLayout.addView(myButton);

        myButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                myButton.setSelected(true);
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: `invalidate` the other `Button` when you select a `Button`.

Comment: what you mean could you explain more specifically?

Answer (score 0):

Create a reference to the previously selected button. Then in your on click method you could do something like this :

```
    myButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if(previousButton !=null)
                previousButton.setSelected(false);
            myButton.setSelected(true);
            previousButton = myButton;
        }
    });
```